# Adding right-click menu items to shortcut with InnoSetup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Is it possible with InnoSetup to add additional right-click menu options for a specific shortcut?

Say my shortcut has a target of `"%localappdata%/Programs/MyApp/app.exe"` that is run on double-click. But my `app.exe` takes some additional command line options that I'd like to abstract, say for "safe mode". Does InnoSetup support adding a menu item that would read "Run in safe mode" and would have a target of `"%localappdata%/Programs/MyApp/app.exe" --safe`?

Comment: Inno supports adding registry entries with whatever values you want so I don't see why not.

Comment: @Anders True. I suppose a better question is how to add to the context menu for a specific shortcut, not all shortcuts.

Comment: I don't see how this is Inno related at all, seems like a regular shell question to me? It might be possible to do this but it would slow down the context menu of all shortcuts. I know the Internet Explorer desktop icon did this sort of thing but that was not actually a shortcut file.

Comment: @Anders It's Inno related because I use Inno to create the shortcut and install the application, seems correlated and tightly coupled to me

Comment: As @Andres suggested, you will probably have to find out or propose or ask separately about technical solution on the Windows/Shell level that does what you want. And we can then help you implementing that in Inno Setup. In general what you ask for is not a common thing to do. So you would need someone both with very good Windows Shell knowledge and Inno Setup knowledge. You might have problems finding anyone to answer your current broad question.

Comment: The only thing that I know that can achieve this is registering a specific extension/file-type. And place a file with that extension on desktop instead of the shortcut.

Comment: I agree with the others, split this into 2 questions.